# JSONP events give unauthorized message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, jquery-events

The code below is throwing error without going to .fail or .always when it receives "401 - Unauthorized" error.  Is there a way to trigger fail and retrieve the error [myErrorMessage] that comes in response from server?

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        url: "http://[myDomain]/[myPage]",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "myFunction"
    })
        .done(function() { alert("success"); })
        .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
        .always(function() { alert("complete"); });

    function myFunction(data) {
        alert("callback");
    }

});
```

**Request Result**

```
GET http://[myDomain]/[myPage]?callback=myJsFunction&_=1361463044315 HTTP/1.1
Host: [myDomain]
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
Referer: http://[myTotallyDifferentDomain]/Default.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

**Response Result**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 16:10:42 GMT
Content-Length: 67

{"Message":"[myErrorMessage]"}
```

**Chrome Result**

```
GET http://[myDomain]/[myPage]?callback=myJsFunction&_=1361463044315 401 (Unauthorized) jquery.min.js:5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP requests do not go to the fail handler on error as of jQuery 1.9, this is the documented behavior.

There isn't a way around it as far as i know. (other than using a proxy, of course)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thx.  I already checked the site before I post here.  Looking for a workaround even if it will force me to use lower version of jQuery.  Since behavior causes the exception I need to suppress that.

Comment: @cilerler As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/NtzLQ/1/ errors due to things such as 404 401 or 500 can't be caught when using a <script> tag.

Comment: Thanks for the demo but I understand the part that I can't catch it which is OK.  But I need to suppress the throwing.  I mean I don't need to know what happen that's fine, but when it gets 500etc. it throws that regardless of the try-catch or .ajaxError than it causes page to stop. :(

Comment: hmm... it shouldn't affect the code execution, it isn't a code error.

Comment: In any case, you can supress the error completely by making the request on your server and having the client request from your server as a proxy.

Comment: my bad, as you said "it shouldn't affect the code execution, it isn't a code error" helped me to realize that this is not an issue.  Thank you!  Also found this https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp kind of a solution for supressing...  Thanks again